# Как выполнить функцию из iframe в родительском окне?

Tags: php, javascript

Пытаюсь выполнить функцию из ***iframe*** [в родительском окне](http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/aaa/test/), но функция не выполняется. Как правильно её выполнить?

**HTML родительского окна:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="send.php" method="post" target="send">
        <button>Отправить</button>        
    </form>

    <iframe name="send"></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function Alert() {
        alert("555");
    }

});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "window.parent.Alert();";
    echo "</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы она могла выполниться, JS должен быть таким:

```
function Alert() {
    alert("555");
}
```

Вы же заворачиваете код в

```
$(document).ready(function () {...});
```

и это делает функцию "невидимой" в глобальной области окна.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно кто я такой, чтоб осуждать ваши методы работы и скриптинга. Поэтому только по делу:

**1)** у вас в `html` не подключен `jquery`, чтобы исполнять конструкции типа `$(document).ready(function ()`

**2)** вам в принципе `$(document).ready(function ()` для объявления функции не нужен. Т.е. функции объявляются до полного рендеринга страницы для глобальной видимости, т.е. `js` будет просто:

```
function Alert() {
    alert("555");
}
```